# PostgreSQL Sequence Ascending Out of Order

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, sql-order-by

I'm having an issue with Sequences when inserting data into a Postgres table through SQL Alchemy.

All of the data is inserted fine, the `id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY` column has all unique values which is great.

However when I query the first 10/20 rows etc. of the table, the `id` values are not ascending in numeric order. There are gaps in the sequence, fine, that's to be expected, I mean rows will go through values randomly not ascending like:

```
id
15
22
16
833
30
etc...
```

I've gone through plenty of SO and Postgres forum posts around this and have only found people talking about having huge serial gaps in their sequences, not about incorrect ascending order when being created

Screenshots of examples:

[image]

[image]

The table itself has being created through standard DDL statement like so:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schema.table_name (
  id                  BIGSERIAL                                   NOT NULL,
  col1                text                                        NOT NULL,
  col2                JSONB[]                                     NOT NULL,
  etc....
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Tables represent **unordered** sets. The **only** way to guarantee a sorted output is to use `order by`

Answer (score 2):

> However when I query the first 10/20 rows etc. of the table

Your query has no `order by` clause, so you  are not selecting the *first* rows of the table, just an undefined set of rows.

Use `order by` - you will find out that sequence number are indeed assigned in ascending order (potentially with gaps):

```
select id from ht_data order by id limit 30
```

In order to actually check the ordering of the sequence, you would actually need another column that stores the timestamp when each row was created. You could then do:

```
select id from ht_data order by ts limit 30
```

Comment: Ah OK gotcha, thanks for clearing that up, I was unaware of the extent of unorderedness in SQL tables

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is no defined "order" within a SQL table.  If you want to *view* your data in a certain order, you need an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY id;
```

As for gaps in the sequence, the contract of an auto increment column generally only guarantees that each newly generated `id` value with be unique and, most of the time (but not necessarily always), will be increasing.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the info. I need to dig a but deeper into understanding ordering (or lack thereof) in SQL, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

How could you possibly know if the values are "out of order"?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  The only indication of ordering in your table is the `serial` value.

The query that you are running has no `ORDER BY`.  **The results are not guaranteed to be in any particular ordering.**  Period.  That is a very simply fact about SQL.  That you *want* the results of a `SELECT` to be ordered by the primary key or by insertion order is nice, but not how databases work.

The only way you could determine if something were out of order would be if you had a column that separate specified the insert order -- you could have a creation timestamp for instance.

All you have discovered is that SQL lives up to its promise of not guaranteeing ordering unless the query specifically asks for it.